# Dojo create image with link

Tags: dom, dojo

Is there a way to use dojo/dom-construct to create an image element with a link? I am looking for equivalent of the following HTML code:

```
<a href="test.html" target="_blank">
    <img src="/pix/byron_bay_225x169.jpg" >
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

Just do it like this:

```
var anchor= domConstruct.create('a', {
    'href': 'test.html',
    'target': '_blank'
});
var image= domConstruct.create('img', {
     'src': '/pix/byron_bay_225x169.jpg'
});
domConstruct.place(image, anchor);
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
 var img = domConstruct.create("img", {
                 src: "/path/image.png",
                 style: "height:16px;width:16px;",
                 title: "Image",
                 onclick: function(){
                    // onclick event
                 },
                 onmouseenter: function(){
                    // on mouse over event
                 },
                 onmouseout: function(){
                    // on mouse out event
                 }
);
domConstruct.place(img, this.container);
```